# Invoking R automatically

Tags: r, scheduling

I have written an R code which does its job well.
I am operating on a local machine with windows 7

I will have a set of csv files being dumped to a given folder in no fixed time period, it could be every hour , day or may be even month.

My ask is everytime the csv is dumped , my R code should automatically run and analyze the csv

Comment: This is just a question about running a process on a file change in Windows 7. Unless you want to do the change checking in R, by having an R process run all the time checking the file for changes every ten seconds, its not really an R question. If you do want that approach, you should be able to at least start to write the code for it. There are various file operation functions in R that might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however if R constantly keeps checking every 10 secs or so, i believe that wont be the best approach, coz that wud need R to keep on running despite no new files being pumped in.. this is because the rate of file arrival is inconsistent.. my tht was whenever the new files arrives if i can alert and invoke R, tat wud have solved my problem.

Comment: Alternatively, can i convert my code to a webservice using the free version of R.. i saw something called deployR on the licensed version..

Comment: Your R code would just be an infinite loop, with a 10 second (or longer) sleep. Most of the time its asleep, doing nothing, then the file test will not strain your computer, then if there's an update R is ready to run and you'll get the job done quicker because there's no need to start R up. I don't think there's an easy way to wait for file changes in R so you'll have to pick another language... Python can do it...

Comment: Thanks a lot.. very helpful..

Comment: You may have a look at [guard](http://guardgem.org/) for this kind of directory/file checking and action. It's in ruby, so maybe not worth the overhead, but could give you a starting point to mimic in R.